# Issues with neutrinoless double beta decay

Tags: experimental-physics, neutrinos, majorana-fermions

After reading the paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.15016, I realized how subtle is the usual statement that "neutrinoless double beta decay" implies that neutrinos are Majorana particles...

My question is. If we can not practically decide how to distinguish from neutrinoless double beta decay that neutrinos are Majorana particles, how could we decide without it if neutrinos are their own antiparticles?

Comment: In general it is preferred on Physics SE to link to the *abstract* page, not directly to a document file.  It is also useful (to readers) to quote the title and author(s) of the paper.

Comment: several experiments are planned https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino#Majorana_mass

Comment: Neutrinoless, however, also precludes a scalar worth two neutrinos in the products, no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Well, I thought I knew and understood neutrinoless double beta decay until I read the article above and references therein. My master thesis was about neutrinos, and I talked about the (later discovered) coherent neutrino-nuclei scattering and several experiments. Now, after reading that neutrinoless double beta decay is necessary but not sufficient to tell if neutrinos are majorana particles I am puzzled and worried if I will see it in my timelife...